# What must I do to enable intellisense for javascript libraries in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I've made a new .net 6 MVC project in Visual Studio 2022 and I can't seem to get intellisense for javascript libraries. I've installed the following workloads with the Visual Studio 2022 installer:

- ASP.NET and web development
- Azure development
- Node.js development
- .NET Multi-platform App UI development

[image]

I am using the straight out of the box mvc template that comes with Visual Studio. It has jquery, a jquery min, and the map file. It used to be that, if you had the map file, you got intellisense support.

Comment: Have you tried to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/

Comment: JQuery comes installed in the default asp.net mvc template.

Comment: Do you have intellicode (different to intellisense) installed under individual components in the installer? Also, is your version of visual studio up to date?

Comment: Does this doc about [JavaScript IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2022) can help you

Comment: It helps me understand that Visual Studio is not performing the way that docs say that it would. At the bottom of that doc it says, "...and for loose files in your project that match a list of roughly the top 400 most popular JavaScript libraries. For example, if you have jquery-1.10.min.js in your project, the file jquery.d.ts will be fetched and loaded in order to provide a better editing experience. This .d.ts file will have no impact on your project." Well, I am using JQuery 3.5.1. That's a pretty popular library. It is so popular that ASP.NET Core comes with it in the MVC template.

Comment: I using [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). it's show everything! but it's way expensive

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 isn't cheap. As a fully fledged IDE, it should include this sort of productivity capability.

Comment: @tnk479 Maybe you can report this problem in [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) for any solution or update.

Comment: I did just now.